# TYPO3 extbase: send correct response headers for downloads

Tags: typo3

I want to send a download file to the user, but the HTTP headers are sent wrong. I expect `Content-type: application/octet-stream` to be sent, but I still get `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. Can somebody please point me to my mistake?
TYPO3 7.6.22

TypoScript:

```
page_1505214798 = PAGE
page_1505214798 {
    typeNum = 1505214798
    config {
        contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders {
        }
        debug = 0
    }
    10 = USER_INT
    10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        vendorName = DIX
        extensionName = Dixeventmanager
        pluginName = Meeting
        controller = Event
        action = download
        switchableControllerActions {
            Event {
                1 = download
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Extbase Controller Action

```
public function downloadAction() {
    // $fn = ...
    $result = file_get_contents(PATH_site . $fn);
    $this->response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream'); 
    $this->response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'. basename($fn) .'"'); 
    return $result;
}
```

The Content-disposition header with the filename is sent correctly, just the Content-type is overwritten somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the right Content-type via TypoScriptFrontendController (TSFE):

```
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController $typoScriptFrontendController */
$typoScriptFrontendController = $GLOBALS['TSFE'];
$typoScriptFrontendController->setContentType('image/jpeg');
```

Here's an example action:

```
    public function downloadAction() {
        $filename = '/path/to/my/file.jpg';
        $file = file_get_contents($filename);

        /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController $typoScriptFrontendController */
        $typoScriptFrontendController = $GLOBALS['TSFE'];
        $typoScriptFrontendController->setContentType('image/jpeg');

        $this->response->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        $this->response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');

        return $file;
    }
```

Comment: TypoScript 
config.additionalHeaders = Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
overruled setContentType()

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set the headers in the TypoScript using 'additionalHeaders'?

```
additionalHeaders {
   10 {
      header = Content-Type: application/octet-stream
      replace = 1
   }
}
```

Comment: That WOULD work, if the content type was fixed. But it can vary (doc, pdf, ...) - OK, it is not obvious from the test code, where I hardcoded it.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this: in a downloadAction of a Controller

```
    if (file_exists($dlPath)) {
        $filesize = filesize($dlPath);

        $mimetype = $fileReference->getMimeType();

        switch ($this->settings['downloadMode']) {
            case 'inline':
                $contentDispostion = "inline";
                break;
            default:
                $contentDispostion = "attachment";
        }

        //  stream file
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
        header('Content-Disposition: ' . $contentDispostion . '; filename="' . ($showname) . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
        if (ob_get_level()) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }
        readfile($dlPath);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work well with the extbase framework. It is probably not the best idea to exit in an action. And since there are methods for setting HTTP headers, I tend to use them.
But it is a valid PHP solution (when you add the line that outputs the file content).

Comment: okay, maybe you're right. However, it works well for me. (added the line that ouputs the file).